# Python & Visual studio code 2022 CMAKE ignored python search path

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm trying to compile some python cmake project but I hit a wall...
This is my example >

```
set(PY_VERSION 37)
set(PY_EXE "C:/Program Files/Python37")
set(Python3_ROOT_DIR "C:/Program Files/Python37")
set(Python3_FIND_ABI "ON" "3" "7")
set(PYTHON_EXECUTABLE "${Python3_ROOT_DIR}/python.exe" CACHE FILEPATH "Path to the Python executable")


set(PY_BUILD_DEB)
if (${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} MATCHES Debug)
    message("WERE IN DEBUG MODE")
    set(PY_BUILD_DEB "_d")
endif ()
set(_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE "${PY_EXE}/python.exe" CACHE STRING "Path to the Python executable")
set(_PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR "${PY_EXE}/include" CACHE STRING "Path to the Python include directory")
set(_PYTHON_LIBRARY "${PY_EXE}/libs/python${PY_VERSION}${PY_BUILD_DEB}.lib" CACHE STRING "Path to the Python library")


set(OLD_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${PY_EXE})
find_package(Python REQUIRED COMPONENTS Interpreter Development)# HINTS "${PY_EXE}")

#set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${PY_BIND_ROOT}/tools)
#find_package(pybind11)

set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${OLD_PATH})

message("  PYTHON_EXECUTABLE : ${_PYTHON_EXECUTABLE}")
message(" PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR : ${_PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR}")
message("     PYTHON_LIBRARY : ${_PYTHON_LIBRARY}")
message("   Python_LIBRARIES : ${Python_LIBRARIES}")
message("Python_INCLUDE_DIRS : ${Python_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
```

The problem I'm having that hes simply ignoring my python pathing and uses his own one.

He gives me

```
1> [CMake]    Python_LIBRARIES : optimized;C:/Program Files/Python310/libs/python310.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/Python310/libs/python310_d.lib
```

where he should point to 37 one.
No matter what variable/etc I do, hes always stuck to 310 he finds "somewhere".

Any idea how to tell vs to do what hes told to do ? Clion/etc ides work properly.

Comment: Can you not just do `find_package(<PackageName> [version] ...)` [as documented](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html#command:find_package)?

Comment: The way you are using `Python3_FIND_ABI` seems completely inconsistent with its proper usage in [the documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPython.html#hints). The only valid values are `ON`, `OFF`, and `ANY`. And "_Note This hint is useful only on POSIX systems. So, on Windows systems, when Python_FIND_ABI is defined, Python distributions from python.org will be found only if value for each flag is OFF or ANY._". You're on windows.

Comment: @user "I solved" this problem in another post. But lets dig in here as the solution else where is dodgy too... Ok, so I can do find_package, But I want to use specific python in specific location. Normally I would just pass HINTS and path to folder, but apparently vcpkg likes to override that function and throw an error. vcpkg also like to ignore my CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH so its a fun issue...